# Checkbox values not being read properly

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, pymysql

I have a Python program that gets information from a database; in this case, we're making hotel reservations. My issue is that if I use checkboxes and select multiple rooms--only the first in the list shows up. I believe the error to be a counting error of sorts that resides in my `checkDetails` method.

It would appear, then when trying to get the value of the checkbox, it only works for the first checkbox in the list. To be perfectly honest, I'm not 100% sure how to describe the issue. In lieu of words, I've uploaded four gifs showing the issue.

**GOOD:** [Selecting the first two works fine. Selecting the first item alone works as well. No matter what, the first item always works.](http://gfycat.com/SeparateCanineCanadagoose)

**BAD_1:**[Selecting the first item and another item (any item except the second) only displays the first item regardless.](http://gfycat.com/ThornyComplicatedBushbaby)

**BAD_2:**[Selecting any two items that don't involve the first item, results in neither item being displayed.](http://gfycat.com/AccurateElderlyChameleon)

**BAD_3:**[Selecting any single item that isn't the first item results in it not being displayed.](http://gfycat.com/AcrobaticCarelessAfricanrockpython)

```
##(USER)MAKE NEW RESERVATION##
    def searchReservation(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Search Rooms")
    # city option button
        self.cityvariable = StringVar(self.root)
        self.cityvariable.set("Select City")
        w = OptionMenu(self.root, self.cityvariable, "Atlanta", "Charlotte",
                       "Savannah", "Orlando", "Miami").grid(row=0, column=0)
    # start and end labels
        self.startDate = tk.Label(
            self.root, text="Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)") .grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.endDate = tk.Label(
            self.root, text="End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)").grid(row=1, column=1)
    # start and end entries
        self.startStringEntry = tk.Entry(self.root, state=NORMAL, width=10)
        self.startStringEntry.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.startStringEntry.insert(0, '2015-11-23') #TODO debugging--remove
        self.endStringEntry = tk.Entry(self.root, state=NORMAL,     width=10)
        self.endStringEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.endStringEntry.insert(0, '2015-11-25') #TODO debugging--remove
    # search button
        self.search_button = tk.Button(
            self.root, text="Search Availabilities", command=self.makeReservation)
        self.search_button.grid()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def validDate(self, date):
        correctdate = None

        try:
            startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            correctdate = True
        except ValueError:
            correctdate = False

        if correctdate is False:
            messagebox.showerror(
                title="Warning", message="A valid date format is required.")
        return correctdate

    def makeReservation(self):
        if self.startStringEntry.get() == self.endStringEntry.get():
            messagebox.showerror(
                title="Warning", message="Reservation must be at least a day")
        elif not self.validDate(self.startStringEntry.get()) or not self.validDate(self.endStringEntry.get()):
            return
        elif datetime.datetime.strptime(self.startStringEntry.get(), '%Y-%m-%d') > datetime.datetime.strptime(self.endStringEntry.get(), '%Y-%m-%d'):
            messagebox.showerror(
                title="Warning", message="End date must be after start date")
        else:
            self.search_button.config(state='disabled')

            self.root.withdraw()
            self.makeRes = tk.Tk()
            self.makeRes.title("Make a Reservation")
        # date labels
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Start Date") .grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="End Date").grid(row=0, column=1)
            Label(self.makeRes, text=self.startStringEntry.get()).grid(
                row=1, column=0)
            Label(self.makeRes, text=self.endStringEntry.get()).grid(
                row=1, column=1)
            Label(self.makeRes, text='City').grid(row=0, column=2)
            Label(self.makeRes, text=self.cityvariable.get()).grid(
                row=1, column=2)
        # column headers
            roomnumber = tk.Label(
                self.makeRes, text="Room Number").grid(row=2, column=0)
            roomcat = tk.Label(self.makeRes, text="Room Category").grid(
                row=2, column=1)
            capacity = tk.Label(
                self.makeRes, text="Room Capacity").grid(row=2, column=2)
            costperday = tk.Label(
                self.makeRes, text="Cost Per Day").grid(row=2, column=3)
            costextra = tk.Label(
                self.makeRes, text="Extra Bed Cost").grid(row=2, column=4)
            availability = tk.Label(
                self.makeRes, text="Select Room").grid(row=2, column=5)
        # insert available rooms
            sql = """SELECT a.RoomNum, a.Category, b.RoomCapacity, a.CostPerDay, a.ExtraBedCost
                    FROM ROOM a, ROOM_CAPACITY b
                    WHERE a.Category = b.Category
                    AND a.RoomLocation = '""" + self.cityvariable.get() + """'
                    AND (
                    a.RoomNum, a.RoomLocation
                    ) NOT
                    IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT c.RoomNum, c.Location
                    FROM ROOM_RESERVATION c, RESERVATION d
                    WHERE c.ReservationID = d.ReservationID
                    AND c.Location = a.RoomLocation
                    AND d.RefundAmount IS NULL
                    AND """ + self.endStringEntry.get() + """ <= d.EndDate
                    AND """ + self.startStringEntry.get() + """ >= d.StartDate
                    )"""

            cursor.execute(sql)
            self.count = 3
            self.data = []
            for data in cursor:
                self.data.append(data)
                for i in range(5):
                    Label(self.makeRes, text=data[i]).grid(
                        row=self.count, column=i)
                self.count = self.count + 1
            if self.count == 3:
                messagebox.showerror(
                    title="Warning", message="No rooms available for city and dates")
                self.makeRes.destroy()
                self.searchReservation()
            else:
                # making checkboxes to select room
                self.vars = []
                for rowNum in range(3, self.count):
                    self.var = IntVar(self.makeRes)
                    Checkbutton(self.makeRes, variable=self.var).grid(
                        row=rowNum, column=5)
                    self.vars.append(self.var)
                self.check_detail_button = Button(
                    self.makeRes, text='Check Details', command=self.checkDetails)
                self.check_detail_button.grid(row=self.count + 1, column=5)

    def checkDetails(self):
        noneselected = True
        for i in self.vars:
            if i.get() == 1:
                noneselected = False
                break
        if noneselected is True:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Warning", message="No rooms selected")
        else:
            self.check_detail_button.config(state='disabled')

            ttk.Separator(self.makeRes, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(
                column=0, row=self.count+2, columnspan=10, sticky=(W, E))

        # column headers
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Room Number").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=0)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Room Category").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=1)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Room Capacity").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=2)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Cost Per Day").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=3)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Extra Bed Cost").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=4)
            Label(self.makeRes, text="Select Extra Bed").grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=5)

            self.count += 4
            new_count = 0

            for data in self.data:
                print(data, self.vars[new_count].get()) #TODO remove
                if self.vars[new_count].get() == 1:
                    for i in range(5):
                        Label(self.makeRes, text=data[i]).grid(
                            row=self.count + new_count, column=i)
                    new_count += 1

            # making checkboxes to select beds
            self.beds = []
            count = 0
            for rowNum in range(self.count, self.count + new_count):
                if self.vars[count].get() == 1:
                    var = IntVar(self.makeRes)
                    checkBox = tk.Checkbutton(
                        self.makeRes, variable=var).grid(row=rowNum, column=5)
                    self.beds.append(var)
                count += 1
            self.count += new_count
            Label(self.makeRes, text='Total Cost').grid(
                row=self.count + 1, column=2)

            # CALCULATE TOTAL COSTS
            total_cost = 0
            count = 0
            self.new_data = []
            for i in self.data:
                if self.vars[count].get() == 1:
                    total_cost += i[3]
                    self.new_data.append(i)
                count += 1

            val = str(total_cost)
            self.total_costs_entry = Entry(self.makeRes)
            self.total_costs_entry.grid(row=self.count + 1, column=3)
            self.total_costs_entry.insert(0, val)
            self.total_costs_entry.config(state='readonly')
            Button(self.makeRes, text='Update total', command=self.updateTotalCosts).grid(
                row=self.count + 1, column=4)

            Label(self.makeRes, text='Use Card').grid(
                row=self.count + 2, column=2)
            cursor.execute(
                'SELECT CardNum FROM PAYMENT_INFO WHERE Username="' + self.user + '"')
            cards = ['-']
            for i in cursor:
                cards.append(i)
            self.card = StringVar(self.makeRes)
            self.opts = OptionMenu(self.makeRes, self.card, *cards)
            self.opts.grid(row=self.count + 2, column=3)
            Button(self.makeRes, text="Add Card", command=self.addCreditCard).grid(
                row=self.count + 2, column=4)
            Button(self.makeRes, text="Delete Card", command=self.deleteCard).grid(
                row=self.count + 2, column=5)

            Button(self.makeRes, text='Submit', command=self.submitReservation).grid(
                row=self.count + 3, column=5)

    def updateTotalCosts(self):
        total_cost = 0
        count = 0
        self.new_data = []
        for i in self.data:
            if self.vars[count].get() == 1:
                total_cost += i[3]
                self.new_data.append(i)
            count += 1
        count = 0
        for i in self.new_data:
            if self.beds[count].get() == 1:
                total_cost += i[4]
            count += 1
        cursor.execute("SELECT DATEDIFF(%s, %s)",
                       (self.endStringEntry.get(), self.startStringEntry.get()))
        diff = cursor.fetchone()
        diff = diff[0]
        total_cost = diff * total_cost

        self.total_costs_entry.destroy()
        self.total_costs_entry = Entry(self.makeRes)
        self.total_costs_entry.grid(row=self.count + 1, column=3)
        self.total_costs_entry.insert(0, str(total_cost))
        self.total_costs_entry.config(state='readonly')
```

EDIT: Why not just do this?

```
    for data in self.data:
            print(data, self.vars[new_count].get()) #TODO debugging--remove
            if self.vars[new_count].get() == 1:
                for i in range(5):
                    Label(self.makeRes, text=data[i]).grid(
                        row=self.count + new_count, column=i)
            new_count += 1
```

Comment: (Wince) mixing interface and back-end code together like this is begging for headaches; it would be a really good idea to separate your code into layers - one for talking to the database, one for business logic, one for interface code. It'll save you lots of problems down the road.

Comment: @HughBothwell I know. I actually didn't write this section; a team member coded this section and I'm trying to solve it for her. After two hours, I got nothing.

Comment: Have you done _any_ debugging at all? For instance, have you determined whether `self.data` has the data you think it does inside of `checkDetails`?

Comment: @BryanOakley If you looked at the code, you'll notice I have a print statement which displays both the value of the checkbox and the contents of self.data. The value of the checkbox isn't what I'm expecting--otherwise this would be working. The data is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely one problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `tk.Tk()`. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way, and it will yield problems similar to what you're seeing.

If you need additional windows, you must create instances of `tk.Toplevel`.

Another problem is this loop:

```
for data in self.data:
    if self.vars[new_count].get() == 1:
        for i in range(5):
            Label(self.makeRes, text=data[i]).grid(
                row=self.count + new_count, column=i)
        new_count += 1
```

There is a fundamental flaw in the logic. Even though you loop over the data, you keep checking `self.vars[new_count]`. So, even though you eventually land on data item 3, 4, 5, etc, you keep checking `self.vars[0]` over and over and over. Once you find one checked item, you now keep looking at `self.vars[1]` even though you may now be on data item number 3, 4, 5, etc.

One simple fix is to make sure you're iterating over the variables the same as you are iterating over the data values:

```
for var, data in zip(self.vars, self.data):
    if var.get() == 1:
        for i in range(5):
            Label(self.makeRes, text=str(data[i]) + "?").grid(
                row=self.count + new_count, column=i)
        new_count += 1
```

The above assumes there is a 1:1 relationship between the items in `self.vars` and the items in `self.data`. It's hard to tell if that's a valid assumption or not.

Comment: Like I said--I didn't write this code. I have no desire in overhauling it; this answer brings me no closer to solving my issue. I realize the code has its faults--but I highly doubt the multiple instances of `tk.Tk()` matter.

Comment: I did what you said--and still have the same issue.

Comment: @Nxt3: I'm not blaming you. It doesn't matter who wrote the code, it has a fatal flaw. It's much more than cosmetic, you're actually creating a new tcl interpreter and throwing the old one away, which can cause you to lose the values of checkbuttons, etc. Regardless, I've spotted another error in the code and I've updated my answer.

Comment: I should add that fixing the multiple `tk.Tk()` in the entire program has fixed another issue I was having. Thank you for bringing this to my attention! I think I was a little harsh with my initial comment. You're right--this was an issue.

Comment: Couldn't you also just do the proposed in my edit to the OP?

Comment: @Nxt3: probably not. `new_count` is used in several places, so changing when it is computed might have undesired side-effects. I think it's used to define how many new rows are added, so incrementing it when not adding another row would be a bad idea.